# The Universtal Gate U(theta, phi, lamda) in Open QASM vs Qiskit

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I have noticed that Open QASM and Qiskit define the universal single-qubit gate U(lambda, theta, phi) differently. The difference causes a phase difference in RZ, for example.

Has anyone come across this problem? Which should one choose?

Answer (score 2):

The gate U in [OpenQASM 2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.03429.pdf) was defined as a special unitary (i.e. determinant=1). But if you are writing circuits in the OpenQASM 2 language, this choice should not be consequential, as OpenQASM 2 does not have a way of explicitly dealing with global phases (and they are not observable).

[OpenQASM 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2104.14722.pdf) on the other hand has a mechanism for controlling gates. This makes global phases consequential (controlling turns the global phase into a relative, observable phase). It turns out the new definition of U in OpenQASM 3 is the same as the [definition in Qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.UGate.html). If you are writing circuits in OpenQASM 3 or Qiskit, then global phases matter. Therefore you should use this new definition.

(As a side note, the new definition is chosen because standard gates such as Paulis can be derived from it in a more straightforward way).

Comment: There's a issue when you do controlled-gates though, and the phase becomes relevant. We bumped into this issue in our quantum simulator https://github.com/softwareQinc/qpp and compiler https://github.com/softwareQinc/staq To solve the issue, we decided to use a `-DUSE_QISKIT_SPECS=ON/OFF` flag, so when it's ON, it uses qiskit (standard), and when OFF, uses OpenQASM.